# Tweaking a VBScript to refresh external data of all excel files in a directory

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a VBScript I've been using to refresh my excel files external data without actually opening it:

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FILE NAME GOES HERE)
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
oWorkbook.Save

oExcel.Quit
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

I am not sure where or how to implement a loop so it will refresh all xlsx and xls files in the directory it is launched in (ie relative path)

Comment: Please clarify your question. How do you run this? What exactly would you like your script to do? What happens when you run the script above?

Comment: If I drop the vbs file in the directory, when it runs, do the refreshall and save commands for all xlsx files in the directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set rootFolder = fs.GetFolder(fs.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName))
 Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

 oExcel.Visible = True
 oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
 oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
 oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

 For Each file in rootFolder.Files
   If inStr(file.type, "Excel") > 0 Then
     Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(file.path)
     oWorkbook.RefreshAll
     oWorkbook.Save
     oWorkbook.Close
     Set oWorkbook = Nothing
   End If
 Next

 oExcel.Quit
 Set oExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add

```
oWorkbook.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

after

```
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

Then `excel` waits until all data is renewed before it saves the file